# How to start programming simple applications?

Tags: android, android-emulator

i'm beginner, i've installed android sdk n eclipse also... i've written code for temperature conversion i.e from Fahrenheit to Celsius but when i run on emulator the calculation part is not working i.e no error in code part n i think its not accepting the input values.... please help me

Comment: Please provide your code sample.

Comment: you can check that by running on a debug mode(F11). Place some breakpoints(CTRL+Shift+B) on the lines you want to check. For example if you want to check if your application passes through that code line.. And post your codes here for us to help you out.

Comment: First have a look at the samples provided on the Android developer website. Don't just start writing random code.

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one activity, make sure you mentioned it in the manifest.